# Richardson variety over arbitrary field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, schubert-varieties

Let $G$ be a split semisimple algebraic group. Let $B$ and $T$ be borel subgroup ,maximal torus respectively. In this case the Weyl group $W(B,T)$ is a constant finite group scheme. Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup contains $B$, which determined by some simple roots. If $G$ is over an algebraic closed field, the Richardson variety are the closure of intersection of Bruhat cell $B^{+}wP/P$ and opposite Bruhat cell$B^{-}uP/P$. Can we define Richardson variety $X_{w}^{u}(k)$ over an arbitrary field $k$, where $u,w$ are elements of Weyl group, such that the base change to its algebraic closure equals to the usual one that defined over algebraic closed field $\bar{k}$, i.e. I want to know whether the Richardson varieties have integral model?

Comment: I only interest to the case $G=SL_n$

Comment: Over a perfect field this is OK because the Bruhat decomposition is defined over $k$.

Comment: @anon Thank you very much! I want to ask another question:over perfect field, the Bruhat decomposition always give cell decomposition?